# Question about the Assassin (Executioner) Ninja Build

Tags: dnd-4e, house-rules

I'm just getting into 4e D&D, and when I wanted to make an `Assassin (Executioner)` because of his ability to use poisons, I saw the "Way of the Ninja" as a guild choice, looked at it and loved the flexibility it offered.  Where as the other two options were either strictly melee or ranged, Ninja mixed both.

So since the "rulings" on `Kusari Gama` are so ambiguous (with the Character Builder saying one thing and the magazine saying another), I wanted a few opinions and/or new rules.

First, in the Character Builder, the Kusari Gama is found under Superior One-Handed, but it's really Two-Handed.  Second, now it apparently deals 1d10 rather than 1d4 or 1d6.

Also: A few of my skills popped up with "You can roll +2d8 damage once per turn".  I know that +1d8 comes from Executioner Finesse, but where's the other one?

Comment: Hi, Mike, and welcome to the site. I'm not sure I understand the "house rules"/"new rules" part of the question. What problem are you trying to solve that the rules aren't handling currently?

Comment: Mike, what level are you at? Also could you post your character here so that we can take a look? (use the text part form the character builder and paste it in a code block here).

Comment: In general if you have access to the online rules compendium that is where you want to get your definitive info.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith this actually looks like some legitimate confusion with double weapons, hopefully my answer clarifies it a bit.

Comment: @waxeagle Was not countering your answer in anyway. I whole heatedly agree with you; just wanted to add that suggestion for Mike because as a rule of thumb the compendium is the only real rules resource that is always up to date.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith very good point, online compendium is by and large authoritative (and where I get most of my answers for this site)

Answer (score 4):

Lets start with the Kusari-gama

The Kusari-gama is a superior double melee weapon. The main end does 1d10 damage and has a +2 proficiency bonus. The weapon also has the defensive property (a +1 bonus to AC when you wield it along with another melee weapon (in this case the other end of the Kusari-gama)) and the reach property (allowing you to make a melee attack to a square 2 squares away from you instead of 1). And it belongs to the flail group. The secondary end of the weapon deals 1d6 damage and has a +2 proficiency bonus. It is classified as an offhand weapon and a light blade.

The reason it's found under superior 1 handed is that double weapons are considered for nearly all purposes as 2 separate weapons.

To answer your second question, my guess is that your character is level 11. At level 11 attack finesse (executioner) increase to 2d8 instead of 1d8 (it increases to 3d8 at L21).

Comment: The post from Wax was very helpful. How did you end up spec-ing your assassin in terms of at-will/daily/encounter?